# Select subnet_id in matching AZ when deploying multiple instances across 4 AZs

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have a resource bloc that creates 4 additional subnets in an existing VPC:

```
# Create a subnet to launch instances into resource 

"aws_subnet" "mesos_subnet" { 
   vpc_id = "${var.dcos_vpc}" 
   count = 4 
   cidr_block = "${cidrsubnet(var.subnet_range, 4,   count.index)}"
   availability_zone = "${element(split(",", lookup(var.azs, var.region)), count.index)}"     
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true 
  tags { "Name" = "${var.prefix}-${element(split(",", lookup(var.azs,   var.region)), 
 count.index)}-sn" } 

}
```

And I am creating instances using a resource bloc like this, which distributes the instances across the available AZs (4 in this region):

```
resource "aws_instance" "agents" {
instance_type = "m4.2xlarge"
ami = "${lookup(var.amis, var.region)}"
count = "${var.agent_instance_count}"
key_name = "${var.key_name}"
vpc_security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.internal_sg.id}","${aws_security_group.admin_sg.id   }"]
   associate_public_ip_address = true
   iam_instance_profile =    "${aws_iam_instance_profile.agent_profile.name}"
    availability_zone = "${element(split(",", lookup(var.azs,     var.region)), count.index)}"
   subnet_id = "${element(aws_subnet.dcos_subnet.*.id, count.index)}"
    tags {
      Name = "${var.prefix}-mesos-agent-${count.index}"
      owner = "${var.owner}"
    expiration = "${var.expiration}"
  }
  }
```

However, in the subnet selector for the instance creation, I cannot seem to make the instances be created in the subnet with the matching AZ, i.e,
terraform tries to create the instance in a subnet but does not match the correct AZ. So I get this error when applying:

```
 * aws_instance.agents.3: Error launching source instance:    InvalidParameterValue: Value (eu-west-1a) for parameter availabilityZone   is invalid. Subnet 'subnet-xxxxxx' is in the availability zone eu-west-1b
         status code: 400, request id: 26665eee-071b-4ca1-a96b-  19b22c2fff94
 * aws_instance.agents.4: Error launching source instance:    InvalidParameterValue: Value (eu-west-1b) for parameter availabilityZone   is invalid. Subnet 'subnet-yyyyyyyy' is in the availability zone eu-west-  1a
```

I think I need a select statement that can somehow filter out and select the subnet ID (of the created subnets) corresponding to the AZ
that was selected in:

```
 "availability_zone = "${element(split(",", lookup(var.azs, var.region)), count.index)}"".
```

Would anyone know how I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just assign `subnet_id`, the instance will be placed into the proper availability zone (of that very subnet). There is no need to assign both `subnet_id` and `availability_zone`properties for `aws_instance` resource. Both properties are optional. Using just one (subnet) will be sufficient.